# SSDT Project Structure when updating using SchemaCompare

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I have set up my sqlproj project structure based on object type using the import Database wizard and using the Object Type as the folder structure.  ie the same view as you'd get in SSMS or SQL Server Object Explorer

[image]

Yet when using ssdt schema compare to update the project, objects are always imported into **Schema\Object Type** structure, causing the project to turn into a mess of mixed structure.

I cant find anywhere I can change the behaviour of the Schema Compare update to continue to use the **Object Type** structure?

using ssdt 14.0.51215 (Dec 2015)

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but you should be able to move the files around afterwards. If you're regularly importing lots of objects, it might be worth considering putting them in the project first, then publishing the changes from the project. (or doing them as you create them) That would have the benefit of not missing anything because you forgot to import them to the main project.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest submitting this feedback as a suggested improvement to Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)"

Comment: Can upvote for it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/2389154/allow-schema-comparison-to-update-sqlproj-using-object-type)

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to update the sqlproj file directly...

```
  <PropertyGroup>
...

    <DefaultFileStructure>BySchemaType</DefaultFileStructure>
...

  </PropertyGroup>
```

More info on this link... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6bfd561-3e7d-4052-be9c-631037681c3e/default-file-structure?forum=ssdt